# How to break symbiotic relationship between a Sycamore tree and fungal spores?

Tags: trees, mushrooms

Our large sycamore tree appears to have entered into a symbiotic relationship with some fungal spores, resulting in a large number of mushrooms appearing around 3-9' away from the base of the tree. The soil is quite damp, given the current climate (UK), and the number of mushrooms is increasing daily.

How do I break the chain? Or do I just let nature run its course? We have 2 children (9 & 6), and I'd hate for them to get sick as a result of touching any of the mushrooms.

Comment: I have several books that I use to identify edible mushrooms . None ever mentioned any mushroom that is dangerous to touch. And I have touched/picked many different ones with no affect, other than possibly stained fingers.

Answer (score 2):

A photo of the mushrooms would have been helpful to determine what type they are, but mushrooms and toadstools are only the fruiting bodies of fungal mycelium present in the soil. They commonly appear in association with wood fragments or woody stumps present in the ground. Most mycelium are essential to  plant growth and are not a sign of disease, and is everywhere in soil, but there are some fungal growths which might indicate disease of the roots, which is why it would have been helpful to see them.

Mushrooms don't  last long - if you're worried, just twist them off and bin them.

Comment: I'll update the question with some photos

Comment: Include the base of the tree if you can ...

Comment: Photos on hold. My son decided to smash them all whilst playing football.

Comment:  Next year then, unless a random one or two pop up in the next few days..

Comment: They are very prevalent at the moment, I suspect by the weekend there will be a dozen or so.